# Does nesting a block of code within run { } affect efficiency?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am aiming to be as concise and efficient as I could in my code.
I have a block of code that runs every 50 milliseconds under Coroutines, with delay(50).

However, the block is a bit long and is contained under MainFragment class, so I preferred nesting it in run { } so I can occasionally minimize it to not get distracted.

My questions are:
Does this effect performance in anyway?
And is there another service that "run" gives other than nesting a block of code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`run()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) function is [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), so the compiler copies its code into the caller, without the overhead of a function call.

So no, this shouldn't have any performance impact at all.

The main benefits of `run()` are the bundling of statements together before ‘returning’ a value, and scoping (the ability to create local variables).